# Store hours and minutes in java

Tags: jodatime

I use jodaTime in my application an I have to store hours and minutes, e.g. 56:45 (means 56 hours and 45 minutes). I have tried it with LocalTime (joda localtime), but this type only accept hours until 24 and alos is not storable over Spring data in mongoDB. My question now would be which type to use?

Currently I have Strings but I am not very happy about it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should always store date and time in `UTC` as `java.util.Date` in DB.

In your case I think you must use `String` but instead of using hours and minutes, you can use `Period` object as `String`.

I tried something, I hope it helps you.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

        // You have "56:45" as string, firstly change all this values to Period Object including  days, hours and minutes
        Period newPeriod = convertStringtoPeriod("56:45");
        // Store newPeriod as String in DB
        // When using it crate a Period Object from it and use it.
        System.out.println("***  Period in Main Method  ***  =" + newPeriod);
        // now you have a period object including  days, hours and minutes
        System.out.println("***  Days in Main Method  ***  =" + newPeriod.getDays());
        System.out.println("***  Hours in Main Method  ***  =" + newPeriod.getHours());
        System.out.println("***  Minutes in Main Method  ***  =" + newPeriod.getMinutes());

    }

    public static Period convertStringtoPeriod(String hoursAndMinutes) {
        // Firstly create a formatter for your coming String
        PeriodFormatter dateFormat = new PeriodFormatterBuilder().appendHours().appendSeparator(":").appendMinutes().toFormatter();
        // create a period including hours and minutes
        Period period = dateFormat.parsePeriod(hoursAndMinutes);
        // create total duration of this period
        Duration duration = period.toStandardDuration();
        // get days from duration
        long days = duration.getStandardDays();
        System.out.println("day count    =" + days);
        // subtract days millis from total duration millis
        duration = duration.minus(days * (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
        // get hours from duration
        long hours = duration.getStandardHours();
        System.out.println("hour count   =" + hours);
        // subtract hours millis from total duration millis
        duration = duration.minus(hours * (1000 * 60 * 60));
        // get minutes from duration
        long minutes = duration.getStandardMinutes();
        System.out.println("minute count =" + minutes);
        // to Store in DB
        Period periodStoredInDB = new Period(0, 0, 0, (int) days, (int) hours, (int) minutes, 0, 0);

        return periodStoredInDB;
    }
```

And the output is;

```
day count    =2
hour count   =8
minute count =45
***  Period in Main Method  ***  =P2DT8H45M
***  Days in Main Method  ***  =2
***  Hours in Main Method  ***  =8
***  Minutes in Main Method  ***  =45
```

In this case, I suggest you to store `P2DT8H45M` in DB as `String`.

Answer (score 0):

`JodaTime` has the `Period` class that can represent periods of time. Though I think if you want to store say 56 hours, you might need to save it as 2 days and 8 hours then when you parse it back display it however you'd like.

http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/Period.html

Otherwise, take a look at the Java `TimeSpan` class.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/period.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create your own Time class, it might look something like this:

```
public class Time {

    private final int minutesPastMidnight;

    public Time(String timeString) {
        int hours = Integer.valueOf(timeString.substring(0, 2));
        int minutes = Integer.valueOf(timeString.substring(3, 5));
        this.minutesPastMidnight = hours * 60 + minutes;
    }

    public Time(Time time) {
        this.minutesPastMidnight = time.getMinutesPastMidnight();
    }

    private int getMinutesPastMidnight() {
        return minutesPastMidnight;
    }

    public int difference(Time time) {
        return this.getMinutesPastMidnight()
                - time.getMinutesPastMidnight();
    }

    public Time min(Time time) {
        return (difference(time) > 0) ? time : this;
    }

    public Time max(Time time) {
        return (difference(time) > 0) ? this : time;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        int hours = minutesPastMidnight / 60;
        int minutes = minutesPastMidnight - (hours * 60);
        return String.format("%02d:%02d", hours, minutes);
    }
}
```